# Is this limit at infinity negative or positive 1

Tags: limits

> $\lim_{x \to -∞} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}$

I solved it:

$\lim_{x \to -∞} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}} = \frac{x}{x} = 1 , -1$ ?

Since its $x/x$, a negative infinity number divided by another negative infinity number is a positive infinity. But I am told that this limit is $-1$

Comment: For $x<0$ you have  $\sqrt{x^2}=-x>0$ not $x<0$

Comment: More intuitively, for $x\lt 0$, note that the function is always negative.

Comment: $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}} = \frac xx$$ is not true for negative values of $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2(1+4x^{-2}})} = \frac{x}{|x|}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4x^{-2}}}
$$
so
$$
\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}} = \lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x}{|x|} \times\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4x^{-2}}} = -1\times 1 = -1
$$
since
$$
\frac{x}{|x|} = -1
$$
for $x<0$ and $(1+4x^{-2})^{-1/2}\to 1$ as $x\to -\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

To handle limits at $-\infty$ often to avoid possible confusion the simpler way is to set $y=-x \to \infty$ then

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}=\lim_{y \to \infty} -\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+4}} =\lim_{y \to \infty} -\frac y y\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac 4{y^2}}}=-1$$